# UINavigationBar has different height in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

I built an app in interface builder. I use a UINavigationController. Everything is in landscape. When I run the app, the height of the UINavigationBar is CORRECT (32px).

it looks like this (Simulator):

[image: correct UINavigationBar height (32)]

but when I look into interface builder, the UINavigationbar height is 44 px, which is WRONG.

It looks like this (interface builder):

[image: wrong navigation bar height (44px)]

This makes it really hard to edit the UI in interface Builder. When I want to edit the position of any other UI Element, I always have to subtract 12 px for the y-position...

Question: I want my interface Builder to display the navigation Bar correct... with height of 32px. How can I do this???

Comment: If you click on the nav bar, then click on the ruler icon at the top of the panel on the right you should be able to resize the bar to a specific hight

Comment: Thanks for your response. But your solution doesn't work. "Height" is "Not Applicable" in Interface Builder